# How do I make fadeOut blocking in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Pretty much as the question says, I have some code running on an interval:

```
$("#blah").fadeOut(2000);
$("#blah2").fadeIn(2000);
```

I'd like to fadeOut, then fadeIn, rather than have both going simultaneously. Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#blah").fadeOut(2000);
$("#blah2").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
```

Or:

```
$("#blah").fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $("#blah2").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the `callback` functionality to ensure, that the animation completes before calling another. Looks like:

```
$('#blah').fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $('#blah2').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

see. [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#blah').fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $("#blah2").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

> .fadeOut( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
>
> **duration**: A string or number determining
> how long the animation will run.
>
> **callback**: A function to call once the
> animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#blah").fadeOut(2000);
setTimeout('$("#blah2").fadeIn(2000);', 2000);
```